# Store passwords securely in Windows

Tags: c#, winapi, password-protection, account-management, passwordvault

Currently, I'm storing my usernames & passwords in a SQL Server CE database.

I would like to use some Windows API in order to securely store my user passwords, so that no other application running on the machine could read them.

I'm supporting Windows 7, and so I cannot use [Password Vault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465069.aspx)

I've tried to use the [CredWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CredRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374804(v=vs.85).aspx) API, based on the example provided [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peerchan/archive/2005/11/01/487834.aspx).

However, while I successfully managed to store and restore my passwords, I also successfully managed to restore them using a completely different application. Meaning that the only security I have is the key I'm using.

Is there any other viable solution?

Seems like anything that use [Windows Security Account Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756748(v=ws.10).aspx) won't do.

Comment: Why are you storing passwords? Isn't that really bad practise?

Comment: Depending on your scenario, one approach would be to encrypt the passwords yourself (using the cryptography API or the CNG) with a passphrase that the user must enter when your application runs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan UI automation is also another good reason

Comment: @OhadSchneider That makes no sense to me. Are you aware of the concept of salting and hashing passwords?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Suppose I have a UI automation script that opens up GMail.com and needs to sign in with some user name and password. I need to have the automation script actually type in the password. What are you proposing?

Comment: @Ohad That's one use case. Not all use cases are like that. Do you think that Google store your passwords? They don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Data Protection API (DPAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)

- [`CryptProtectData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261(VS.85).aspx) to store the data
- [`CryptUnprotectData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380882(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the data

Data is protected by the user account credentials, so it can be retrieved by other application running under same account. Alternatively you can use the machine credentials to give access to services.

See [Example C Program: Using CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382377(v=vs.85).aspx) for an example.

DPAPI is used by the vast majority of applications to store passwords.

Comment: Anything is keeping any other malicious software that knows my username from encrypting the same string and accessing the SAM?

Comment: @Mugen The password is used in this case, so even if you know the username, you can't read the passwords without the user's password. Bear in mind that applications running in the same context as the user account will be able to read the information, but this is **always** going to be a vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged with `C#`: there is a [.NET managed wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=net-5.0) around [DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), which is easier than using *Interop* code.

A clear example on how to use this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=net-5.0#examples).

If the type `ProtectedData` cannot be found in the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography` make sure to add this `nuget package`:

`Install-Package System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData`